# dynamic dropdown fetching data from database not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a table named `tblstationerystock` having three columns like :-

uin,
orderdate,
quantity.

There are multiple record on different `orderdate` against `uin`.

**My table Structure is:-**

[image]

i have a form in which there are two input drop down (uin and orderdate ) which takes input from table `tblstationerystock`.

If i select the `uin` in the first input drop down box i want the second dropdown box should show only those `date` which belong to that particular `uin`.

**My Problem:-**

But the second dropdown shows all the  value all the time .

**my code for form is**

```
<?php
include('includes/config.php');
?>

<div class="form-group col-md-12">
<label> User Name<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
<select class="form-control" name="user" id="uin" onchange="fnorderdate()" >
<option value=""> </option>
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT uin from  tblstationerystock group by uin order by uin asc ";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{               ?>  
<option value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->uin);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($result->uin);?></option>
 <?php }} ?>
</select>
</div>


<div class="form-group col-md-12">
<label> User Name<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
<select class="form-control" name="user" id="orderdate" >
<option value=""> </option>
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT orderdate from  tblstationerystock group by orderdate order by orderdate asc ";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{               ?>  
<option value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->orderdate);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($result->orderdate);?></option>
 <?php }} ?>
</select>
</div>
<script>
function fnorderdate()
{
    uin=$('#uin').val();
    $.ajax({
        method:"post",
        url:"ajax.php"'
        data:{uin:uin},
        
        success:function(result)
        {
            $('#orderdate').html(result);
        
        

}
</script>
```

**my ajax code is**

```
<?php
include('includes/config.php');
if(isset($_POST[uin]))
{
    $uin=$POST['uin'];
    
    $select="select orderdate from tblstationerystock where uin='$uin' ";
    $query=mysqli_query($conn,$select);
    while($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        echo "<option value='".$data['orderdate']."'>".$data['orderdate']."</option>
    }
}
    


?>
```

Comment: Note that in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate

Comment: And see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries (it's strange that you 'prepare' queries that need no preparation, and then don't prepare the one query that does!)

Comment: @Strawberry plz explain

Comment: @roopa have you solved your problem or not??

Comment: @KUMAR not solved.Kindly help

Comment: @roopa  okay please wait......

Comment: @KUMAR thnx waiting............

Comment: @roopa  in first select uin  list shows correctly??

Comment: @KUMAR yes fist  select list shows all the uin in table

Comment: @roopa have you solved your problem or not??

Comment: @roopa please upvote my answer also.

Comment: @KUMAR i did that thx

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**View Part:-**

```
<?php
include('includes/config.php');
?>
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
<label> UIN<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
<select class="form-control" name="uin" id="uin" >
<option value="" > </option>
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT uin from  tblstationerystock group by uin order by uin asc";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{  ?>  
<option value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->uin);?>">
<?php echo htmlentities($result->uin);?>
</option>
 <?php }} ?>
</select>
</div>


div class="form-group col-md-12">
<label> ORDER DATE<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
<select class="form-control" name="orderdate" id="orderdate" >

</select>
</div>
```

**jQuery / AJAX Code:-**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#uin').on("change",function () {
        var uin = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "uin="+uin,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $("#orderdate").html(response);
            },
        });
    }); 

});

</script>
```

make a php file name it **ajax.php** in same directory

and put this code:-

```
<?php 
include('includes/config.php');
$uin = $_POST['uin'];
echo "<option>Select ORDER DATE</option>";
$sql = "SELECT orderdate from  tblstationerystock WHERE uin=$uin";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{               ?>  
<option value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->orderdate);?>">
<?php echo htmlentities($result->orderdate);?>
</option>
 <?php }}
 ?>
```